# Query to find the city name with longest and shortest length

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, subquery, union

I've written a query to return me the cities with the shortest and longest length strings in a MS SQL SERVER database.

```
Select city, len(city) as l 
From Station Where len(city) in 
((select max(len(city)) from station)
Union
(select min(len(city)) from station)) 
Order by l,city;
```

My difficulty is that I get duplicates, because I have a few cities that have the longest and shortest length. Also when I try to `ORDER BY CITY` in both sub queries it fails.

Any advice?

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]. Then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: (Clearly) Your error(s) & goal will be faqs. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way:

```
select * from (
         select top 1 city, LEN(city) cityLength from station order by cityLength ASC,city ASC) Minimum
       UNION
       select * from (
       select top 1 city, LEN(city) cityLength from station order by cityLength desc, city ASC) Maximum
```

Comment: Works great. Do you know where I can find info on the use of minimum and maximum used that way? I only know of the min(attribute) and max(attribute) aggregates used in the Select portion of a query.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly where to look, but I basically just got the Top 1 while selecting the Len(city) and ordering it by "asc" and "desc". This will get the min and max in each of those selects.

Answer (score 3):

I might do:

```
select top (1) with ties city
from station
order by len(city) asc
union 
select top (1) with ties city
from station
order by len(city) desc;
```

Or:

```
select distinct city
from station
where len(city) = (select max(len(city)) from station) or
      len(city) = (select min(len(city)) from station);
```

Comment: what is ``ties`` supposed to do? I get a run time error with the first query. Also not sure what the difference is between Union and UNION ALL but I can google that!

The second Query gives me the same result as mine (still has duplicates)

Comment: Use 'select distinct city...'

Answer (score 0):

Select City, length(City) from Station where City in (Select City from Station where length(City) in (Select max(length(City)) from Station)) OR City in (Select min(City) from Station where length(City) in (Select min(length(City)) from Station)) order by City asc;

Comment: This does not really answer the question. It would be great if you could add an explanation. Why is this snippet the solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it

```
Declare @ShortLength INT 
SET @ShortLength = (SELECT MIN(LEN(CITY)) FROM STATION)
Declare @LongLength INT 
SET @LongLength = (SELECT MAX(LEN(CITY)) FROM STATION)
SELECT TOP (1) CITY AS City, LEN(CITY) AS ShortLength FROM STATION WHERE LEN(CITY) = 
@ShortLength ORDER BY CITY ASC
SELECT TOP (1) CITY AS City, LEN(CITY) AS LongLength FROM STATION WHERE LEN(CITY) = 
@LongLength ORDER BY CITY ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  CITY, LENGTH(CITY) lengthOfCity FROM STATION
ORDER BY lengthOfCity asc, CITY asc
LIMIT 1;
SELECT  CITY, LENGTH(CITY) lengthOfCity FROM STATION
ORDER BY lengthOfCity desc, CITY asc
LIMIT 1;.
```

You need to use ORDER BY  with 2 variables to justify the condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @min as int 

Declare @max as int 

select @min =min(len(city)) , @max =max(len(city)) From Station

Select city , lengthcity From (
        Select city,len(city)lengthcity, row_number() over(partition by len(city) order by city)rn from Station where len(city) in (@min , @max) 
        )   a
where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Simple way for solving this

```
(Select Distinct CITY, Length(CITY)
FROM STATION 
WHERE LENGTH(CITY) IN
(Select MIN(Length(CITY)) from STATION)
Order BY CITY ASC
LIMIT 1)
UNION
(Select Distinct CITY, Length(CITY)
FROM STATION 
WHERE LENGTH(CITY) IN
(Select MAX(Length(CITY)) from STATION)
Order BY CITY ASC
LIMIT 1)
```